# Perl - custom keystroke handlers

Tags: perl

I'm trying to implement custom handlers for given keystrokes so that I can change mode when my script is fetching data from file. How is that possible without any WHILE loop?

I was looking into `Term::ReadKey` but I dont think it does what I need. Maybe I should connect it with something though I can't find any solution on google.

I've just started with `perl` scripting :)

Comment: Is reading from a file a long process?

Comment: You do not need a while loop to call `ReadKey`. If there is a keystroke ready to be read it will return it, if not just continue fetching data from the file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to avoid busy waiting when waiting for a keyboard input:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open2;

my $pid1 = run_cmd('read_key');
my $pid2 = run_cmd('counter');

print "Master: waiting for keyboard event..\n";
waitpid $pid1, 0;
print "Master: Done.\n";
kill 'TERM', $pid2;

sub  run_cmd {
    my ($cmd) = @_;

    open(OUT, ">&STDOUT") or die "Could not duplicate STDOUT: $!\n";
    open(IN, ">&STDIN") or die "Could not duplicate STDIN: $!\n";
    my $pid = open2('>&OUT', '<&IN', $cmd);
    return $pid;
}
```

where `read_key` is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadKey;

ReadMode 4;
END { ReadMode 0 }
my $key = ReadKey(0);
print "$key\n";
```

and `counter` is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{TERM} = sub { die "Child (counter): Caught a sigterm. Abort.\n" };
my $i = 0;
while (++$i) {
    sleep 1;
    print "$i\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
Name "main::IN" used only once: possible typo at ./p.pl line 19.
Name "main::OUT" used only once: possible typo at ./p.pl line 18.
Master: waiting for keyboard event..
1
2
3
q
Master: Done.
Child (counter): Caught a sigterm. Abort.
```