# Waiting for a defined period of time for the input in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

What is the way to say

> wait for the 10 sec for the input
>   if no input recognized
>   print something

in Perl?

Comment: Maybe this could be used: [Perl - custom keystroke handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637326/perl-custom-keystroke-handlers)

Comment: Perl Cookbook describes a solution involving [IO::Handle](http://p3rl.org/IO::Handle), [IO::Select](http://p3rl.org/IO::Select), and [Symbol](http://p3rl.org/Symbol).

Comment: This [discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=282322) may help you.

Answer (score 3):

[`IO::Select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) and `can_read` with a timeout.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Select;

my $select = IO::Select->new();
$select->add( \*STDIN );

my $input = "NONE";
if ( $select->can_read(10) ) {
    $input = <STDIN>;
}

print "Got input of $input\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`alarm()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html),

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub timeout {

  my ($f, $sec) = @_;

  return eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die };
    alarm($sec);
    $f->();
    alarm(0);
    1;
  };
}

my $text;
my $ok = timeout(sub{ $text = <STDIN>; }, 10);

if ($ok) {
  print "input: $text";
}
else {
  print "timeout occurred\n";
}
```